# UISearchbar's scopebar show when scroll the searchResultsTableView

Tags: iphone, ios, tableview, uisearchbar

I have a UISearchbar with searchDisplayController that drag to my tableview via IB. My search scope bar hidden when it's not in search mode. When I start to search the scopebar will show like the image below [image: show scopebar when in search mode]

then I type my text and search result it show when I scroll the result scopeBar hide like this [image: After enter the text and scroll]

so what should I do to show the scope bar when scroll ?

this is my code:

```
- (void)searchDisplayControllerDidBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller {
    controller.searchResultsTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    controller.searchResultsTableView.bounces = NO;
}

- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.showsScopeBar =YES;
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar sizeToFit];
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: please post the code of - (void) searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar  method..

Comment: @ParasJoshi: i edit my question and add the code. I didn't use  - (void) searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar

Comment: ok anywhere you set No for showscopebar?? means you hide it anywhere just check and also add as a subview of a view not a UITableView

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem 
In

```
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
```

I set the

```
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.showsScopeBar
```

to NO. so when I scroll the tableview this method call and hide the scopebar